# $_FILES array and its silly structure

Tags: php, file, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you loop through $_FILES array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444827/how-do-you-loop-through-files-array)

For some reason arrays really get to me.  I can get there in the end, but this $_FILES array seems to be backwards to me.

I want to be able to loop through $_FILES like so:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{
   echo $file['name'] . "<br>";
   echo $file['type'] . "<br>";
   echo $file['size'] . "<br>";
   echo $file['error'] . "<br>";
}
```

But obviously with the way its structured you cannot do that.  So I have written the following:

```
echo "<pre>";
                $x=0;
                $file = array();
                foreach($_FILES['attachment']['name'] as $data)
                {   $file[$x]=array(); 
                    array_push($file[$x],$data); $x++;
                }
                $x=0;
                foreach($_FILES['attachment']['type'] as $data)
                    {   array_push($file[$x],$data); $x++;}

                $x=0;
                foreach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'] as $data)
                    {   array_push($file[$x],$data); $x++;}
                $x=0;
                foreach($_FILES['attachment']['error'] as $data)
                    {   array_push($file[$x],$data); $x++;}
                $x=0;
                foreach($_FILES['attachment']['size'] as $data)
                    {   array_push($file[$x],$data); $x++;}
                var_dump($file);
                echo "</pre>";
```

Which seems very long winded and rediculous but my mind is stuck at the moment as to how to loop through properly the different parts of this array to get it work and loop the way I want it to.

There must be a better way?

Please help!

Comment: When someone struggles and wants to learn, I hate to give them the answer. Rather, I can provide links and resources to help them understand better. The following two links provide insight into your issue along with some explanations as to why. Take a look at this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444827/how-do-you-loop-through-files-array I would also suggest a read on this comment in the PHP.Net manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#106608

Comment: You are trying to loop through all files in some directory?

Comment: For the record, `$_FILES` is a stupid structure and illustrates exactly what is wrong with PHP very well. It is a language designed by many people over the years who haven't stopped and though about things before they do them. It is slowly getting better, but things will never really improve until some "deprecated" things actually start being removed in a timely manner. Casing point: `the following deprecated alias may be used: mysql_numrows()` - that's right, a deprecated alias of a deprecated function, still available in 5.4. It was deprecated so long ago it's not even in the PHP4 changelog.

Comment: The $_FILES array structure is most likely an artifact of how IETF MIME transport over HTTP works (and probably some SAPIs).  If you send a multipart form but no file is selected, the $_FILES array is still populated!  PHP's execution cycle is highly dependent upon the SAPI and the incoming data stream.  Parsing MIME is not magical or pretty.  I'd like to see you parse incoming MIME and tell me that you've got it all figured out.  Microsoft's been handling MIME content for over two decades with Outlook and *still* haven't perfected it.  IETF MIME is a convoluted mess.  Blame the IETF, not PHP.

Comment: PHP is a language where the developers have the tendency to not break existing userland software. I, for one, appreciate not having to waste my time/energy rewriting my software every year from the ground up because someone decided to immediately change everything to meet the latest "best practice" fad. If the existing superglobal bothers you that much, then write a function that "fixes" it. PHP is open source software: No one has any right to complain about PHP/Zend engine if they've never cracked open the PHP source code and aren't on the PHP internals mailing list, which are open to all.

Comment: I wrote a library that makes dealing with the `$_FILES` array as simple as dealing with the `$_POST` array, the way everyone expects until they find out the hard way. https://github.com/tvanc/files-array-organizer

Answer (score 6):

If they all have the same length you can do it like this

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['attachment']['name']); $i++)
{
   echo $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i] . "<br>";
   echo $_FILES['attachment']['type'][$i] . "<br>";
   echo $_FILES['attachment']['size'][$i] . "<br>";
   echo $_FILES['attachment']['error'][$i] . "<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 3):

From your code, i suppose your `<form>` inputs look like this:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]">
<input type="file" name="attachment[]">
```

If you give unique names to the file fields you should get the `$_FILES` structure you want:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment0">
<input type="file" name="attachment1">
```

results in something like this:

```
array(2) {
  'attachment0' => array(5) {
    'name'     => string(8) "1528.jpg"
    'type'     => string(0) ""
    'tmp_name' => string(0) ""
    'error'    => int(2)
    'size'     => int(0)
  }
  'attachment1' => array(5) {
    'name'     => string(8) "1529.jpg"
    'type'     => string(0) ""
    'tmp_name' => string(0) ""
    'error'    => int(2)
    'size'     => int(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: no, it just has one input with `multiple` tag.

Comment: That would be a good info to add to the question.