# how upload photo to mysql via php5

Tags: php, mysql, blob

i have a problem upload image at DB mysql like blob type i'm going include  script db and the code of form and php upload file

sql script

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `data` longblob NOT NULL,   `descripcion` varchar(240) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish2_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

---

index.html(upload form)

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="insertar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>elige imagen:</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="file" name="imagen"/>
        <br/>
        <label>descripcion:</label>
        <br/>
        <textarea cols="20" rows="10" name="texto"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

insertar.php(upload code)

```
<?php
    include "conexion.php";


    $archivo=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    $texto=$_POST['texto'];
    $id=rand(1,200);

    $insertar=mysql_query("INSERT INTO image VALUES('".$id."','".$archivo."','".$texto."')");

    if($insertar){
        echo "<a href='verImagenes.php'> ver mis imagenes</a>";
    }else{
        echo "fallo la insercion";
    }
?>
```

and this is the error message:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo\insertar.php on line 9

Comment: `$_FILES['imagen']` is an array of values containing information on the file that was uploaded. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445223/1745573

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to store the *$_FILES* array in your database? *$_FILES* is an array that stores information about the file you just uploaded, hence the array-to-string error.

When you upload a file, the file is temporarily stored on the server. You need to handle the file upload correctly - i.e. save it somewhere and then store this path in your database.

You could always serialize the *$_FILES* array and store it, though I don't know what use this would be considering it only references a file that is temporarily on your server.

Comment: i dont need store the path i need store the photo itself like blob

Comment: You can always open the $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'] (temporary location of file once uploaded) with something like fopen() and store the contents in SQL, though this sort of goes against how file uploads are supposed to be handled...