# How to loop through $_FILES?

Tags: php, html, file

I want to add loop around $_FILES[] array. I tried `$count=   count($_FILES['files'][name])` and then add loop around it  `for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)`, but it is not giving me desired output.

I want add to loop only from the files that the User is uploading, Right now it is counting all of the 'files' available in the form.

Kindly tell me a way to count only the uploaded files and loop through them.

Comment: Try without `[name]` like `count($_FILES['files'])` instead of `count($_FILES['files'][name])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444827/how-do-you-loop-through-files-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop ever the `$_FILES` array and use the `['name']` inside the iteration:

```
$count = count($_FILES['files'])
for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {
  if ($_FILES['files'][$i]['size'])
    echo $_FILES['files'][$i]['name']."\n";
}
```

Even easier is to use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($_FILES['files'] as $file) {
  if($file['size'])
    echo $file['name']."\n";
}
```

Comment: With foreach, you will get 5 elements in array no matter what your array's length is. For that reason, array will need to be recreated with organized order. Like explained here http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for that. You filter the array to just get the inputs with uploaded files in them.

```
$uploaded_files = array_filter($_FILES['files'], function($file){ 
    return $file['size']; 
});

print count($uploaded_files);

foreach($uploaded_files as $file)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: can i use this for filtering out empty files ? for a multiple upload FILES data

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the files in the following way:

```
$count = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
    $file_error = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understood from your question,`$_FILES['files']` is array of uploaded file ,so you can act it like array. try [foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $file){
    // now do something with $file
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $file["name"]);//e.g uploading it
}
```

Comment: This will loop from all of the files available in the Form. I want to loop only from the files that user is selecting.