# Count the total variables inside an array with multiple upload files

Tags: php

I dont know what the problem is, but I always get a return of 5. i have already set `php.ini max_file_upload` to 99999, but it still gets stuck on 5. This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="img[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$img = '';

if ( !empty ( $_FILES['img'] ) ) {

$e = count ( $_FILES['img'] );

echo $e;

for ( $i=0; $i <= $e; $i++ ) {

move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$i], "upload/" . $_FILES["img"]["name"] = $i.'.jpg'); 

}
```

I tried to upload **10** files but the variable `$e` from `count()` returns a max of **5**. How do I  get the value for `$e` to reflect how many files it uploaded? For example, if I upload **10** files then `$e` from count then it will return **10**.

Comment: Probably Apache or IIS, or whatever the *web server* is has 5 set as the limit.

Comment: No, i have see the default is 20. and if i set value $e manually. it work. the problem is how to get total variabel.

Comment: I think this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/18401278/2662489 Perhaps some of your files have 0 for file size.

Comment: `developerwjk` i see the answer. it can used `count($_FILES['img'])` to get number of files upload. but it stuck to 5 on me.