# if ($_POST) always returns false

Tags: php, html

I'm having some trouble with a Form. It contains an input type File for uploading an image, and a select tag to choose where to put this image.
Code goes like this:

```
<?php
require_once("functions.php");
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']))
  {
    $username= checkcookie($_COOKIE['user']);
  }
  if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
if ($_POST) {

    $errors = array();
    $errors = SomeValidation();

    if (empty($errors )) {
      UpdateImages();
      exit;
    }else {
      Header ("location: somefile.php?error=There was an error");
      exit;
    }
}else{
  var_dump("error");
} ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
         <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <?php if(isset($_GET['error']))  {?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <ul>
                    <li><?php echo $_GET['error'] ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

              <div class="cbp-mc-column">

                <label>Choose new Image</label>

                <select id="code" name="code">
                  <option value="1" >First</option>
                  <option value="2" >Second</option>
                  <option value="3" >Third</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="file" name="newimage" value="" />
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
                <br>
              </div>

           </form>

         <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
         <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
<?php }else
{
  header('location: panel.php');
}
?>
```

I'm always getting False for `if($_POST)`, and also when I submit the form.
Any idea why?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I'm sending the `select` value via post, so I can choose which file upload, and It is always empty.

Comment: Why don't you do this, `if(isset($_POST['update'])){ ...`?

Comment: Is $_POST totally empty? what does a print_r($_POST) give ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to upload image or any other file you need to check the $_FILES array not post,
this question could be helpfull

[How do you loop through $_FILES array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444827/how-do-you-loop-through-files-array)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check inputs instead of request method.. so use

```
if (!empty($_POST["update"])) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check if the **submit** button was clicked :`isset($_POST['update'])`

Next, check if a file has been selected: `isset($_FILES['newimage']['tmp_name'])`

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

   if (isset($_FILES['newimage']['tmp_name'])) {

        $errors = array();
        $errors = SomeValidation();

        if (empty($errors )) {
            UpdateImages();
            exit;
        } else {
             Header ("location: somefile.php?error=There was an error");
             exit;
        }
   } else {
        echo "No file selected.";
   }

} else {

     echo "Not a POST request.";
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting false, i'm going to try starting the code from cero.