# uploading multiple images at once to folder not working

Tags: php

so i have a form that is sended to a function inside the same page. Now single file upload works. But when it comes to uploading multiple files it starts giving errors. I tried googling it but on what way i search the first 3 result pages are all read and noc result.

So my form :

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-send'])){

    $foto           = $_FILES['image'];
    $img_ff = 'image'; // Form name of the image
    $dst_img = strtolower($_FILES[$img_ff]['name']); // This name will be given to the image. (in this case: lowercased original image name uploaded by user).
    $dst_path = '../images/project/' ; // The path where the image will be moved to.

    $overig->uploadimage($img_ff, $dst_path, $dst_img);
}
?>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="w3-container" style="background-color: white;" action="" method="post">
               <div class="w3-row-padding">
                   <div class="w3-half">
                       <div class="w3-group">
                           <label class="w3-label w3-text-teal"><b>Selecteer Foto(s)</b></label>
                           <input class="w3-input" type="file" id="image" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">
                       </div>
                   </div>

                   <div class="w3-half">
                       <div class="w3-group">
                           <label class="w3-label w3-text-teal"><b>Toevoegen</b></label>
                           <input type="submit" value="Voeg dit project toe" name="btn-send" class="w3-btn w3-blue-grey">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </form>
```

and my function page where the result is being send too

```
    public function uploadimage($img_ff, $dst_path, $dst_img){

                $dst_cpl = $dst_path . "/". basename($dst_img);
                $dst_name = preg_replace('/\.[^.]*$/', '', $dst_img);
                $dst_ext = strtolower(end(explode(".", $dst_img)));

                while(file_exists($dst_cpl) == true){
                    $i = $i+1;
                    $dst_img = $dst_name . $i . '.' . $dst_ext;
                    $dst_cpl = $dst_path . basename($dst_img);
                }

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$img_ff]['tmp_name'], $dst_cpl);

                $dst_type = exif_imagetype($dst_cpl);

                if(( (($dst_ext =="jpg") && ($dst_type =="2")) || (($dst_ext =="jpeg") && ($dst_type =="2")) || (($dst_ext =="gif") && ($dst_type =="1")) || (($dst_ext =="png") && ($dst_type =="3") )) == false){
                    unlink($dst_cpl);
                    die('<p>The file "'. $dst_img . '" with the extension "' . $dst_ext . '" and the imagetype "' . $dst_type . '" is not a valid image. Please upload an image with the extension JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF and has a valid image filetype.</p>');
                }
}
```

everytime the error i get is :

> The file "1." with the extension "" and the imagetype "" is not a valid image. Please upload an image with the extension JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF and has a valid image filetype.

Can someone please help me?

**Vardump before the foreach**

```
    array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "socket.jpg"
  }
  ["type"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
  }
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpQIXgAp"
  }
  ["error"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(146543)
  }
}
```

**vardump after foreach**

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "socket.jpg"
}
```

Comment: `$_FILES` structure is different if one or multiple files are uploaded. duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444827/how-do-you-loop-through-files-array ?

Comment: @Zimmi to be honest i am not really that experienced and i can't really make up a lot of sense out of that post :C sorry..

Comment: Don't worry. First, turn on error reporting, so that you can see all notices, warnings and errors. Your code generates some usefull ones... it will give you many information you need. The thing is : you have an input element of type `file` named `image[]`. This is an array of files : correct as you want to enable multiple file upload. But this means that `$_FILES[$img_ff]['name']` is an **array of filenames** indexed from 0, not the file name as a string. The same for  `$_FILES[$img_ff]['type']` and so on. Try also `var_dump($_FILES)`. Once you have fixed all warnings, come back if needed

Comment: @Zimmi the weird problem is, there are no errors. when i var dump before the foreach i get everything the name, type,tmp_name etc etc but when its in the foreach and do a var dump it only shows the photo complete name. I updated the post with the results to see.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no foreach in the code you provided. Cannot help further in such cases. With the code provided, `$_FILES[$img_ff]['name']` is an array, as you can see in the var_dump you gave, so `$dst_img = strtolower($_FILES[$img_ff]['name']);` is `null`