# Filled up $_FILES doesn't return file extension

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops

I wrote this short script to upload multiple files, based on an old topic from Stackoverflow : [How do you loop through $_FILES array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444827/how-do-you-loop-through-files-array)
(I didn't reply into it as it's 7 years old... Let me know if I did wrong)

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName) {
        if(!empty($tmpName) && is_uploaded_file($tmpName)) {
            $img_url = url_rewrite($intitule).'-' . time() . $i . '.'.strtolower(substr(strrchr($tmpName, '.'),1));
            $gallery = $gallery . '|' . $img_url;
            move_uploaded_file( $tmpName, $dir_upload . '/' . $img_url);
        }
        $i++;
    }
 }
 echo $gallery;
```

So basically, I'm sending multiple files in $_FILES['images'] and I create unique names before upload (using time() + $i). I never get the file extension as $_FILES['images']['name'] seems to be empty. It's not though as Var_dump returns a complete array with everything I need :

```
array(1) {
  ["images"]=> array(5) { 
    ["name"]=> array(5) { 
      [0]=> string(13) "my-file-1.jpg" 
      [1]=> string(13) "my-file-2.jpg" 
      [2]=> string(13) "my-file-3.jpg" 
      [3]=> string(13) "my-file-4.jpg" 
      [4]=> string(13) "my-file-5.jpg" 
    }
    ["type"]=> array(5) { 
      [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
      [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
      [2]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
      [3]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
      [4]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=> array(5) { 
      [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/php1Nrgb4" 
      [1]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpnIJHZa" 
      [2]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpcAEf1c" 
      [3]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpbHgrVj" 
      [4]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpGu0FIp" 
    } 
    ["error"]=> array(5) { 
      [0]=> int(0) 
      [1]=> int(0) 
      [2]=> int(0) 
      [3]=> int(0) 
      [4]=> int(0) 
    } 
    ["size"]=> array(5) { 
      [0]=> int(262684) 
      [1]=> int(15644) 
      [2]=> int(32638) 
      [3]=> int(11897) 
      [4]=> int(103303) 
    }
  }
}
```

I'd also need ['type'] to test the files but same thing : I Can't get to return the array's content.

Do you see something wrong in this script ?

Comment: _"`$_FILES['images']['name']` seems to be empty."_  it's pretty clear from your `var_dump()` that it is far from empty

Comment: That's why I'm asking for help. I tried a Foreach on $_FILES['images']['name'] instead of 'tmp_name' and nothing appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_FILES['images']['tmp_name']` does not contain an extension, that is the temp file PHP made of the uploaded file.

If you want the filename with extension of the file that was uploaded from the users PC, you need to look in `$_FILES['images']['name']`

So

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName) {
    if(!empty($tmpName) && is_uploaded_file($tmpName)) {
        $img_url = url_rewrite($intitule)
                    .'-' 
                    . time()
                    . $i 
                    . '.'
                    . strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['images']['name'][$index], '.'),1));
                    // changed here -----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $gallery = $gallery . '|' . $img_url;
        move_uploaded_file( $tmpName, $dir_upload . '/' . $img_url);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Also you can simplify that bunch of functions that get the extension to

```
        $img_url = url_rewrite($intitule)
                    .'-' 
                    . time()
                    . $i 
                    . '.'
                    . pathinfo($_FILES['images']['name'][$index], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $gallery = $gallery . '|' . $img_url;
```

Comment: Thanks you @RiggsFolly, it's working that way. i guess I forgot the [$index].
But why can't I use foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $index => $tmpName) instead ?
(I'm keeping your suggestion, but I'm being curious about it)

Comment: Because you need that, to be the location and name of the TMP file so that `move_upload_file()` will move the tmp file.