# How to loop this code to compress multiple image at a time

Tags: php, html, image-compression

This is my code to compress images in php but i don't know how to loop them so user may enter multiple files and then it's get convert. Is it is possible to do???
Here's my php code snippet

```
<?php
/*$input_image="sample.jpg";
$output_image="output.jpg";

$img=imagecreatefromjpeg($input_image);
imagejpeg($img,$output_image,10);*/
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $info=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if(isset($info['mime'])){
        if($info['mime']=="image/jpeg"){
            $img=imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        }elseif($info['mime']=="image/png"){
            $img=imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        }else{
            echo "Only select jpg or png image";
        }
        if(isset($img)){
            $output_image=time().'.jpg';
            imagejpeg($img,$output_image,40);
            echo "Processing done";}
    }else{
        echo "Only select jpg or png image";
    }
}
?>
```

My html code snippet

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: This is basically anwered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444827/how-do-you-loop-through-files-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you loop through $\_FILES array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444827/how-do-you-loop-through-files-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_am'])) { 

    // Start of Image Upload
    foreach($_FILES["pro_image"]["name"] as $key=>$val) {
        $info=getimagesize($_FILES['pro_image']['tmp_name'][$key]);
        if(isset($info['mime'])){
            if($info['mime']=="image/jpeg"){
                $img=imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['pro_image']['tmp_name'][$key]);
            }
            elseif($info['mime']=="image/png"){
                $img=imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['pro_image']['tmp_name'][$key]);
            }
            elseif($info['mime']=="image/gif"){
                $img=imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['pro_image']['tmp_name'][$key]);
            }
            elseif($info['mime']=="image/jpg"){
                $img=imagecreatefromjpg($_FILES['pro_image']['tmp_name'][$key]);
            }
            else{
                echo "Only select jpg or png image";
            }

            if(isset($img)){
                $newFileName=$user_id.$email.$filename.$count.'.jpg';
                $file = $newFileName.'_'.$val;
                imagejpeg($img, "../media/listing/$file" ,20);

                $imagedata = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO ready_to_move_image(property_id, user_id, username, pro_image) values ('{$property_id}', '{$user_id}', '{$username}', '{$file}')");
            }
        }
    }
}
```